# bootstrap 5 + wordpress front page break design scroll left

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-5

bootstrap 5 + wordpress front page break design scroll left

any idea what the problem is?
thanks

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AMeJ.jpg)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJyM7.jpg)

Comment: It could be anything. Forgot to close a tag?

Comment: I will look again and update thanks